# Dividing polygon value according to number of raster cells overlayed in R

Tags: r, polygon, raster

At the moment I'm working with the `raster` package. I've different polygons with certain values (let's say 100), which I managed to `rasterize`. The problem is that when I `rasterize` each raster cell result with a value of 100, but I want the polygon value (100), to be equally divided per each cell overlaying the polygon. For example, if the polygon overlay 100 raster cells, I want each raster cell to have a value of 1, instead of 100. Could anyone help me?
Here the raster abd the shp I created: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B6-UFgI67v99c3ZhUFp0eWpzOGM
I tried to do something like that:

```
ncell<-freq(union,digits=6)
ncell[,"value"]/ncell[,"count"]
new<-rep(c(union[,"value"],ncell[,"count"]))
union$new<-c(new)
```

but I cannot join the column I obtain in the raster associating the raster cells with the new values.

Comment: The best way to get help is to provide a reproducible example, including sample data and code.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways I can think of:

1. compute the number you want for the polygons, before using rasterize
2. use freq as you did, but then use subs

for example:

```
r <- subs(union, data.frame(ncell)) 
x <- union / r
```